# AngularJs+Spring MVC 3.0. Page is not displaying because controller in spring work incorrect(

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

Good morning) 
I'm faced with difficult for me situation. 
I'm creating application, back end in spring mvc and client - in angular js.
Project has next structure:

```
-src/
    -main/
         -java/
              -mvc/
                  -MessagesController.java
-src/
    -main/
         -webapp/
                -resources/
                          -angular/
                                 -controllers/
                                             -messageController.js
                                 -factories/
                                            -messageFactory.js
                                 -app.js
                -WEB-INF/
                        -views/
                              -messages/
                                       -layout.html
                               -main-layout.html
```

And this is Java controller:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/messages")
public class MessageController {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(MessageController.class);

    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    private final Twitter twitter;
    private final Facebook facebook;

    private static String TWITTER_NETWORK = "twitter";
    private static String FACEBOOK_NETWORK = "facebook";
    private static int MAX_TWEET_COUNT_PER_PAGE = 199;
    private static int MAX_FACEBOOK_POTS_PER_PAGE = 199;
    private List<String> twitterUsers = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Autowired
    public MessageController(MessageRepository messageRepository,
            Facebook facebook, Twitter twitter) {
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.twitter = twitter;
        this.twitterUsers.add("rianru");
        this.twitterUsers.add("riabreakingnews");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/messagelist.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Message> list() {
        getMessagesFromSocialNetworks();
        List<Message> messages = messageRepository.getSortedByDateMessageList();
        return messages;
        // return new ModelAndView("messages/inbox", "messages", messages);
    }

    public void getMessagesFromSocialNetworks() {
        if (facebook != null) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            List<Post> fbPosts = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed("me", 0,
                    MAX_FACEBOOK_POTS_PER_PAGE);
            parseAndSaveFacebookPosts(fbPosts);
        }
        if (twitter != null) {
            List<Tweet> tweets = twitter.timelineOperations().getUserTimeline(
                    MAX_TWEET_COUNT_PER_PAGE);
            for (String user : this.twitterUsers) {
                tweets.addAll(this.twitter.timelineOperations()
                        .getUserTimeline(user, MAX_TWEET_COUNT_PER_PAGE));
            }
            parseAndSaveTwitterPosts(tweets);
        }
    }

    private void parseAndSaveFacebookPosts(List<Post> fbPosts) {
        if (!fbPosts.isEmpty()) {
            List<Message> existingFacebookPosts = messageRepository
                    .findByNetwork(FACEBOOK_NETWORK);

            for (Post fbpost : fbPosts) {
                Message socialPost = new Message();

                socialPost.setSocialId(fbpost.getId());
                socialPost.setCreatedAt(fbpost.getCreatedTime());
                socialPost.setText(fbpost.getMessage() != null ? fbpost
                        .getMessage() : fbpost.getStory());
                socialPost.setNetwork(FACEBOOK_NETWORK);

                socialPost.setAuthorPicture("https://graph.facebook.com/"
                        + fbpost.getFrom().getId() + "/picture");
                if (!existingFacebookPosts.contains(socialPost)) {
                    try {
                        socialPost = messageRepository.save(socialPost);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.info("Ahtung!");
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.warn("This post already exist");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseAndSaveTwitterPosts(List<Tweet> tweets) {
        if (!tweets.isEmpty()) {
            List<Message> existingTwitterMessages = messageRepository
                    .findByNetwork(TWITTER_NETWORK);
            for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
                Message socialPost = new Message();
                socialPost.setSocialId(String.valueOf(tweet.getId()));
                socialPost.setCreatedAt(tweet.getCreatedAt() != null ? tweet
                        .getCreatedAt() : null);
                socialPost.setText(tweet.getText());
                socialPost.setNetwork(TWITTER_NETWORK);

                socialPost.setAuthorPicture(twitter.userOperations()
                        .getUserProfile(tweet.getFromUserId())
                        .getProfileImageUrl());
                if (!existingTwitterMessages.contains(socialPost)) {
                    try {
                        socialPost = messageRepository.save(socialPost);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.info("Ahtung!");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


     @RequestMapping("/layout")
     public String getMessagePartialPage(ModelMap modelMap) {
     return "messages/layout";
     }
}
```

And app.js:

```
    'use strict';
var Messages = {};
var app = angular.module("Messages", [ 'Messages.factory' ]);

app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/infoboard/messages', {
        templateUrl : 'messages/layout',
        controller : MessageListController
    }).when('/infoboard/messages/:id', {
        templateUrl : 'messages/show',
        controller : MessageDetailController
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/infoboard/messages'
    });
} ]);
```

MessageFactory.js

```
var app = angular.module('Messages.factory', []);
app.factory("MessageFactory", function($http, $q) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    return {
        publishMessage : function(socialId) {

            var dataString = {
                'socialId' : socialId
            };
            return $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : "/infoboard/publishPost",
                params : dataString
            });
        },
        onloadMessages : function(dataString, url) {
            var returnData = "";

            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : url,
                params : dataString
            }).success(
                    function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        angular.forEach(data, function(elem) {
                            var cratedDate = new Date(elem.createdAt);
                            var months = [ '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06',
                                    '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12' ];
                            var year = cratedDate.getFullYear();
                            var month = months[cratedDate.getMonth()];
                            var date = cratedDate.getDate();
                            if (date < 10) {
                                date = "0" + date;
                            }
                            var hour = cratedDate.getHours();
                            var min = cratedDate.getMinutes();
                            var sec = cratedDate.getSeconds();
                            var time = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + ' '
                                    + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
                            elem.createdAt = time;
                        });

                        returnData = data;
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject("An error occured while fetching items");
            });
            return returnData;
        }
    };
});
```

And MessageController.js

```
    var MessageListController = function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.messages = [];
    $scope.fetchMessages = function() {
        $http.get('/infoboard/messages/messagelist.json').success(
                function(messages) {
                    $scope.messages = messages;
                    console.log("Success");
                });
    };
    $scope.fetchMessages();
};
```

Main-layout.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Messages">
<head>
<title>Infoboard</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css"
    type="text/css" media="screen"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/application.css"
    type="text/css" media="screen"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"
    type="text/css" media="screen"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src=http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.4/angular-resource.min.js></script>
<script src="resources/angular/app.js"></script>
<script src="resources/angular/factories/messageFactory.js"></script>
<script src="resources/angular/controllers/messages.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Wrap all page content here -->
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="/infoboard/messages">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a href="/infoboard/connect">Connections</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="container" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and messages/layout.html:

```
<div class="twitter_container" ng-controller="TweetController">
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-switch="{{message.network}}"
        ng-switch-when="'twitter'" class="twitter">
        <span><input type="checkbox" name="active"
            ng-checked="{{message.isPublished}}" data-id="${message.socialId}"
            ng-click="publishMessage($event)" /></span> <span><img
            src="{{message.authorPicture}}" /></span> <span>{{message.createdAt}}</span>
        <span>{{message.network}}</span> <span>{{message.text}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="twitter" ng-repeat="tweet in tweets">
        <span> <input type="checkbox" name="active"
            checked="{{tweet.isPublished}}" data-id="{{tweet.socialId}}"
            ng-click="publishMessage($event)" /></span> <span><img
            src="{{tweet.authorPicture}}" /></span> <span>{{tweet.createdAt}}</span> <span>{{tweet.network}}</span>
        <span>{{tweet.text}}</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn twitter-posts"
        ng-click="onloadTweets($event)">Get more tweets</button>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div class="facebook_container" ng-controller="FacebookController">
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-switch="{{message.network}}"
        ng-switch-when="'facebook'" class="facebook">
        <span><input type="checkbox" name="active"
            ng-checked="{{message.isPublished}}" data-id="{{message.socialId}}"
            data-createdAt="{{message.createdAt}}"
            ng-click="publishMessage($event)" /></span> <span><img
            src="${message.authorPicture}" /></span> <span>{{message.createdAt}}</span>
        <span>{{message.network}}</span> <span>{{message.text}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="facebook" ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <span> <input type="checkbox" name="active"
            checked="{{post.isPublished}}" data-id="{{post.socialId}}"
            data-createdAt="${post.createdAt}" ng-click="publishMessage($event)" /></span><span><img
            src="{{post.authorPicture}}" /></span> <span>{{post.createdAt}}</span> <span>{{post.network}}</span>
        <span>{{post.text}}</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn facebook-posts"
        ng-click="onloadFacebook($event)">Get more facebook posts</button>
</div>
```

I suppose problem with controller, because page doesn't rendering and redirection me to my error page(

Comment: What is exception your getting back on UI or do you see any exception in server console ?

Comment: In `MessageController.js`, I see `$http.get('/infoboard/messages/messagelist.json')` , have you tried changing it to $http.get('/messages/messagelist.json') ? . Seems like may be url is wrong `/infoboard` not required ?

Comment: infoboard is a name of my application, deployed into tomcat.I'm also trying sent get request at "/messages/messagelist.json". The same result(

Comment: The result is http://puu.sh/5mQLX.png )